# How to add a custom id to each post URL in wordpress

Tags: php

I'm working on wordpress site. I use custom post type as my post type. I want to add custom id with character to post url like `www.mydomain.com/g123/postname/`. And i also need if i delete `/postname/` part from url it must be redirect to the post `www.mydomain.com/g123/postname/`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i wasn't able to add custom id but i show the post id in url with a character like this `www.mydomain.com/%category%/g%post_id%/%postname%/`